# Scrapy on a JSON response

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am having a problem scraping a json response in Scrapy. I am getting the following error:

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'Response'

I have tried to decode it using the following by importing codecs and decoding the response to utf-8, but it isn't working for some reason.  The code:

```
import scrapy
import json

class SrealitkyBuySpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "srealitky_buy"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.sreality.cz/"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.sreality.cz/api/cs/v2/estates?category_main_cb=1&category_type_cb=1&per_page=20&region=Praha']

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response)
        print(jsonresponse)
```

I also tried adding .text to the response when using json.loads, but then I get the error that "response has no attribute 'text'".

```
jsonresponse = json.loads(response.text)
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Thanks Cuber, I just edited my first question. I tried adding reponse.text to the json.loads, but then I get the error "AttributeError: Response object has no attribute 'text'"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `type(response)` it would be `scrapy.http.response.text.TextResponse`

And `response.body` will give `b'{"meta_description": "5192 realit v nab\\u00eddce prodej byt\\u016f, .... "collective"}}'`

So you need to use

```
jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body)
print(jsonresponse["meta_description"])
'5192 realit v nabídce prodej bytů, Praha. Vyberte si novou nemovitost na sreality.cz s hledáním na mapě a velkými náhledy fotografií nabízených bytů.'
```

**Edit-1**

If the above doesn't work for you because of Python version try below

```
jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Thanks! It is still not working though, using the json.loads(response.body) I get a new error saying: "TypeError: the JSON must be str, not 'bytes'"

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: python version 3.4.2, I actually took a look at the type(response) and it actually says <class 'scrapy.http.response.Response'>, so not getting the same response as you did?

Comment: I hope you are on the latest Scrapy version? I test on the latest one

Comment: Scrapy 1.1.1 version, I installed it through Conda just this morning?

Comment: Your edited response worked to decode to utf-8, I had then to also run chcp 65001 in windows console to make it print correctly. Thanks!!