# Python loop through nested JSON object without root element

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I've already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818782/iterate-through-nested-json-object-and-get-values-with-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784067/scrapy-on-a-json-response).

I have the following json which has no root element and I want to loop through each item in `objects` and print the value for `object_code`:

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "objects": [
    {
      "object_code": "HN1059"
    },
    {
      "object_code": "HN1060"
    },
    {
      "object_code": "VO1013"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried:

```
json='{"count": 3,"objects": [{"object_code": "HN1059"},{"object_code": "HN1060"},{"object_code": "VO1013"}]}'

for obj in json['objects']:
    print(obj.get('object_code'))


for obj in json[0]['objects']:
    print(obj.get('object_code'))
```

Neither work and I get the error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

**UPDATE 1**

The suggested solutions don't work for me, maybe that's because I'm using it in the context of a Scrapy class, here's the full code that throws error

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
import json
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mytest'
    start_urls = []

    def start_requests(self):
        s='{"count": 3,"objects": [{"object_code": "HN1059"},{"object_code": "HN1060"},{"object_code": "VO1013"}]}'
        obj = json.loads(s)
        for o in obj['objects']:
            print(o.get('object_code'))
```

Comment: your `json` contains JSON content : so a string, not a python structure

Comment: Your JSON is a string (thank you for correctly using the word JSON!). But why do you think you can manipulate that serialized data like unserialized data?

Comment: You could post a new question about your update. Include Scrapy in the tags if it's required to reproduce the issue. See [mre].

Comment: @wjandrea I'll do that. As a best practice, should I delete this question since it's a duplicate anyway? Or would that not be fair to folks who already provided answers?

Comment: @Adam I don't see any reason to keep it around personally, but I don't know if you can delete it when there's an answer with a positive score.

Comment: @wjandrea just tried to delete, I indeed can't "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it."

Answer (score 2):

You need to load fom the JSON content to python structure

```py
import json

value = '{"count": 3,"objects": [{"object_code": "HN1059"},{"object_code": "HN1060"},{"object_code": "VO1013"}]}'
content = json.loads(value)

for obj in content['objects']:
    print(obj.get('object_code'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to convert the JSON string to a dict.

```py
import json
s='{"count": 3,"objects": [{"object_code": "HN1059"},{"object_code": "HN1060"},{"object_code": "VO1013"}]}'
obj = json.loads(s)
for o in obj['objects']:
    print(o.get('object_code'))
```

Comment: This gives me error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: @Adam It runs fine: https://ideone.com/v0Zx7H

Comment: @Adam Please provide a [mre] if there is a problem.

Comment: @Adam Maybe your problem is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784067/scrapy-on-a-json-response

Comment: I don't think so. That actually loads and tries to parse a Scrapy response object, but I'm just trying to parse a string, I never do anything with a response object...

Comment: @Adam I don't see any reason for that not to work then.